# Page not using template given to wp_insert_post()

Tags: wordpress

I've created a new page with the code below:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_content'   => "My page content", 
    'post_title'     => "Page for product 1234", 
    'page_template'  => "listing.php"
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
echo "<br /> ID returned from wp_insert_post is $post_id";
```

I tried in the array to make the page use "listing.php" as the template but when I put http://example.com/?p=61 into my browser address bar, where 61 is the `$post_id` returned by `wp_insert_post()` above, the page is found but it's using "single.php" as the template.

Why didn't it use "listing.php", and how can I make it use "listing.php"?

BTW, I know "listing.php" is a valid template because it shows up in the Template dropdown if I try to create a new page from WP-Admin | Pages | Add New.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `post_type`, otherwise WordPress will default to a post (which ignores the `page_template` parameter).

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_content'   => "My page content", 
    'post_title'     => "Page for product 1234", 
    'post_type'      => 'page', // Add this
    'page_template'  => "listing.php"
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

From the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Parameters):

> `page_template:` If `post_type` is 'page', will attempt to set the page template. On failure, the function will return either a WP_Error or 0, and stop before the final actions are called. **If the post_type is not 'page', the parameter is ignored.** You can set the page template for a non-page by calling `update_post_meta()` with a key of `_wp_page_template`.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in WP 5.5.3.
Arg 'post_type' equal 'page' added,  but wp_insert_post ignore this parameter.

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags('Chart Manager'),
  'post_content'  => $page_content,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_slug'     => 'chartmanager',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'page_template' => plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'templates/cm_index.php'
);
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```